# How do I export a table from 1 database to another database in Oracle (sql plus)

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

If I have 1 table in a database, and I want to export it, then import it into new table in a different database?

Should I set up the table with same fields in database two, or is there a way create empty table so all the import will work?

Comment: you can do this if you use oracle 11g or 12c.. it was answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902102/oracle-import-data-into-a-table-with-a-different-name

Comment: Thanks, I'm on 12.10.10 so it should work if I give it a try. Could i import a backup to create new table if there is no table already though.

Comment: see this parameter `TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION` sample here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_table_exists_action_impdp.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dblink established, a quick way to copy a table without intermediate files would be to execute this from the target database (the one where you want the new table to be copied):

```
create table my_new_table as
select *
from my_original_table@my_original_database
```

This presupposes the dblink, of course, and also that there is sufficient redo space to allow that much data to be copied in one fell swoop.

If not, you could also build the table this way and then do a bunch of `insert into` transactions to move the data in chunks.

If you only want the structure (your question sort of implied that, but I wasn't sure), you can always add a `where 1 = 3` to copy only the structure.

This won't import constrains or indexes, but I'm not sure if that matters for what you seek.